# How to get translated coordinates from mouse position

Tags: c#, wpf, image, 2d

I have a form in WPF. It contains Image what can be moved and scaled. Here is the code responsible for moving and scaling:

```
        MatrixTransform finalTransform = null;

        Matrix translateMatrix = new Matrix();
        translateMatrix.Translate(TranslationOffset.X, TranslationOffset.Y);

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.ScaleAt(Scale, Scale, image1.Width / 2, image1.Height / 2 );

        finalMatrix = scaleMatrix * translateMatrix;

        finalTransform = new MatrixTransform(finalMatrix);
        image1.RenderTransform = finalTransform;
```

Now, I click by LMB on image and I want to get image coordinates from mouse position.

I mean if I click on upper-left corner of image I will get (0,0) (regardless of image position and scale), when click on bottom-right corner then I will get e.g. 640x480 (for image size 640x480).

I think, I shall do something with matrices but I don't know what exactly.

Answer (score 2):

It think it is quite simple: `Point relativeToPicture = e.getPosition(myPicture);`